# need to skip command arguments inside library

Tags: linux

I want to skip command arguments in the initialization section of a library. The init section of the library is:

```
static void pa_init_services (void) __attribute__((constructor (102)));
static void pa_init_services()
```

IE, it gets executed before the main() call inside the program. I want to implement what I'll call "tear off" arguments, that is to say I want to look at the front of the arguments, check if the argument pertains to my library, then parse those options just for my library, then remove them from the list before main() gets them. I don't control what program contains the main(), this is for a general purpose library that gets linked in to the client program.

If, for example, I can actually get access to the argv POINTER, and actual argc location, then I can do the parse and skip procedure simply.

This procedure is mentioned (for example) in the GTK documentation, GTK parses options specific to it, and skips them before the client program gets them.

Comment: [`gtk_init`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-init) doesn’t “grab” arguments on its own, it needs to be given pointers to the arguments, and it modifies those — it’s not transparent.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I see that. So no way to do this from a add-on library eh?

Comment: Yes, there is, see mosvy’s answer; I only wanted to point out that Gtk doesn’t work the way your last paragraph suggests it does.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux[1], you can override the `__libc_start_main()` function (the wrapper which calls the `main()` function) from your library. You can do that multiple times.

Example:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE     /* for RTLD_NEXT */
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <err.h>
#ifdef __UCLIBC__
#define __libc_start_main       __uClibc_main
#endif
#define STR_(s) #s
#define STR(s)  STR_(s)
int __libc_start_main(
        int (*main)(int,char**,char**), int ac, char **av,
        int (*init)(int,char**,char**), void (*fini)(void),
        void (*rtld_fini)(void), void *stack_end)
{
        typeof(__libc_start_main) *real_lsm;
        if(*(void**)&real_lsm = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, STR(__libc_start_main)))
                return real_lsm(main, ac - 1, av + 1, init, fini, rtld_fini, stack_end);
        else
                errx(1, "BUG: dlsym: %s", dlerror());
}
$ cc -fPIC -shared -Wall -W -Wno-parentheses skip.c -o skip1.so -ldl
$ cc -fPIC -shared -Wall -W -Wno-parentheses skip.c -o skip2.so -ldl
$ LD_PRELOAD="./skip1.so ./skip2.so" /bin/echo a b c d
c d
```

This also works if you link a program against the `skip1.so` , etc libraries explicitly. You can even `execve()` a completely different program with completely different arguments from there.

[1] This also happens to work with `musl`, though its `__libc_start_main` doesn't take a `rtld_fini` argument. In uclibc, the equivalent function is `__uClibc_main`.

Answer (score 0):

Might have found my own answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998143/alternative-way-to-obtain-argc-and-argv-of-a-process

```
__attribute__((constructor)) void stuff(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        printf("%s: argv[%d] = '%s'\n", __FUNCTION__, i, argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Of course, the issue remains of skipping the arguments, IE, you can look at the arguments but the main() program will fail when it finds your lib arguments mixed with its own.

Comment: Yea, I'm thoroughly convinced its a bad idea. Might help someone else though.